What does systemd do in the background to determine the cause of a service stop?
We have HBase service configured as follows:
[Unit]
Description=Hbase

[Service]
Type=forking
User=hbase
Group=hbase
WorkingDirectory=/opt/hbase
ExecStart=/opt/hbase/bin/hbase-daemon.sh start regionserver
ExecStop=/opt/hbase/bin/hbase-daemon.sh stop regionserver

LimitNOFILE=128000
TimeoutSec=300

Restart=always
RestartSec=300
StartLimitBurst=10
StartLimitInterval=3600

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

When I manually stop HBase using the command /opt/hbase/bin/hbase-daemon.sh stop regionserver, systemd restarts the service automatically. However, when I use systemctl stop hbase, the service stops as expected and does not restart.
Could you please explain why this is occurring?
What does systemd do in the background to determine the cause of a service stop?

Start by reading man systemd systemctl. If you have configured systemd to ensure hbase is running, your manual stop looks like a failure,  and systemd restarts it. When you tell systemd to stop HBase, it knows not to restart.


Could you please explain why this is occurring?

It doesn't have to "determine in background" anything. In the 2nd case, you told systemd to stop the service, therefore it already knows that the stop was user-initiated from the very beginning.
In the 1st case, of course, you're not telling systemd to stop the service; so as far as systemd is aware, the service's main process appears to exit entirely on its own. This means that the Restart= parameter applies, and systemd restarts the service as configured. It does not try to determine what prompted the process to exit.
(And because the parameter has been set to Restart=always (and not, for example, Restart=on-failure), systemd does not check the exit status or anything; it just restarts the service in all cases other than systemctl-initiated stop.
If the service had been configured with Restart=on-failure, then (in the 1st case) systemd would look at the exit code of the main process, and would skip the restart if the process returned 0 (success), as many services do so when asked to exit.)
